# Из файла в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, словари

Есть файл:

```
Daniel, 2  
20, slow, card 
3, quick, card  
30, slow, cash  
17, normal, card  
Katka, 1.5  
13, slow, cash  
24, normal, card  
Robo, 1  
5, normal, cash  
11, quick, card  
8, slow, card  
Sandra, 1.25  
38, slow, cash
```

нужно получить:

```
my_list = {('Daniel', 2.0): [(20, 'slow', 'card'), (3, 'quick', 'card'), (30, 'slow', 'cash'), (17, 'normal', 'card')],('Katka', 1.5): [(13, 'slow', 'cash'), (24, 'normal', 'card')], ('Robo', 1.0): [(5, 'normal', 'cash'), (11, 'quick', 'card'), (8, 'slow', 'card')], ('Sandra', 1.25): [(38, 'slow', 'cash')]}
```

Это первая часть задания, вторая часть - посчитать длинну очереди  (время ожидания):

```
n=0
array1=[]
speed=0
d={}
with open("D:\F\sample1.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        array1=line.strip().split(', ')
        if (len(array1)==2):
            data=''
            if len(k)>0:
               k=k+']'
               # тут формирую справочник
               d[k]=data
            kassir=array1[0]
            speed=float(array1[1])
            k='('+"'"+kassir+"'"+'), '+str(spped)+': ['
            print(" Key "+k)
            n=+1
        else:
            print(" P "+str(array1))
            q_=float(array1[0])
            type_kust=array1[1]
            type_pay=array1[2]
            if len(data)>0:
               data=data+', ' 
            data='('+str(q_)+', '+"'"+type_kust+"', '"+type_pay+'")'
            print(data)
    k=k+']'
    d[k]=data
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: а по какому принципу считается время ожидания и что это? ))

Comment: там есть условие. скорость обработки кассиром товара в сек, тип покупателя медл/сред/быстр  скорость выкладки товара 8/6/3 тип  оплаты карта для всех 4 и по типу покупателя для налички тоже отличается, и все это складывается в кучу и для всех кто в очереди конкретной кассы (кассира) и количество товара у покупателя

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Для **sample.txt** с содержимым:

```
Daniel, 2
20, slow, card
3, quick, card
30, slow, cash
17, normal, card
Katka, 1.5
13, slow, cash
24, normal, card
Robo, 1
5, normal, cash
11, quick, card
8, slow, card
Sandra, 1.25
38, slow, cash
```

можно использовать такой код:

```
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = dict()

for line in lines:
    line_elements = line.replace('\n', '').split(', ')

    if line_elements[0].isalpha():
        current_cashier = (line_elements[0], float(line_elements[1]))
        data[current_cashier] = []
    else:
        customer = (int(line_elements[0]), line_elements[1], line_elements[2])
        data[current_cashier].append(customer)
```

в итоге в `data` будет словарь

```
{
    ('Daniel', 2.0): [(20, 'slow', 'card'), (3, 'quick', 'card'), (30, 'slow', 'cash'), (17, 'normal', 'card')], 
    ('Katka', 1.5): [(13, 'slow', 'cash'), (24, 'normal', 'card')], 
    ('Robo', 1.0): [(5, 'normal', 'cash'), (11, 'quick', 'card'), (8, 'slow', 'card')], 
    ('Sandra', 1.25): [(38, 'slow', 'cash')]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо - код понятен мне, сам бы не долго к такому шел, опыта нуль, но это поправимо. Спасибо Добрый Человек!

Comment: @Леонид, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)