# получить словарь из файла python

Tags: python, yaml

есть файл txt, содержащий следующую инфу:

```
- name: python-3.8.9-amd64.exe\n
  link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd64.exe\n
  sha256summ: e15bc52914b6daee9630360bfe3708ee646d4e4ce34bf5368066213009af70a6\n
- name: python-3.8.9-amd645.exe\n
  link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd645.exe\n
  sha256summ: e15bc52914b6daee9630360bfe3708ee646d4e4ce34bf5368066213009af70a6
```

для примера повторяется два раза, может быть бесконечным, мне нужно получить список, содержащий `name: link: sha256sum:` лучше в цикле, для дальнейшей обработки списка, сохранять его не нужно

Comment: добро пожаловать! Предоставьте вашу пробу пера, тут не решают за вас поставленные задачи, а вот помочь разобраться могут. Приложите ваш код и задайте вопрос в стиле: "Что не получается"

Comment: Пример вопроса по вашей теме можете подсмотреть здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1260616/209304

Comment: Файл в формате YAML. `pip install pyyaml`. `import yaml` и вперёд.

Comment: @Dmitry, по факту (см.ниже) вы не правы. Тут периодически "решают за вас поставленные задачи".

Comment: @Сергей это их выбор, я им не могу запретить  или разрешить. Этот вопрос поднимался не раз уже, и не стоит акцентировать на это внимание и устраивать холивары не относящиеся к вопросу здесь. На мете им место. Я лишь отметил почему вопрос может быть вдруг закрыт и у ТСа возникнет вопрос и негодование: "Почему?". 3 голоса за закрытие и -1

Comment: @Dmitry, я просто отметил неточность в комментарии. "Сайт не предназначен для решения за вас поставленных задач" будет более точно.

Comment: @Сергей субъективно, внесите предложение на мете, какие формулировки применять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по виду, формат этого файла - [YAML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Устанавливаете `pyyaml` (`pip install pyyaml`), дальше парсится фактически в одно действие:

```
file = """
- name: python-3.8.9-amd64.exe\n
  link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd64.exe\n
  sha256summ: e15bc52914b6daee9630360bfe3708ee646d4e4ce34bf5368066213009af70a6\n
- name: python-3.8.9-amd645.exe\n
  link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd645.exe\n
  sha256summ: e15bc52914b6daee9630360bfe3708ee646d4e4ce34bf5368066213009af70a6
"""

import yaml
from pprint import pprint

pprint(yaml.safe_load(file))
```

Вывод:

```
[{'link': 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd64.exe',
  'name': 'python-3.8.9-amd64.exe',
  'sha256summ': 'e15bc52914b6daee9630360bfe3708ee646d4e4ce34bf5368066213009af70a6'},
 {'link': 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd645.exe',
  'name': 'python-3.8.9-amd645.exe',
  'sha256summ': 'e15bc52914b6daee9630360bfe3708ee646d4e4ce34bf5368066213009af70a6'}]
```